# locked out with system lock screen on swipe

Tags: lock-screens

I have an lg rebel lte from tracfone with android  5.1. I install a custom locker and then somehow set the system lock to swipe. Now when i try to unlock the phone it says systemUI has stopped and touch input fails. Tried reboot and and cant boot recovery mode. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a factory reset to gain access to your phone. **If factory reset don't solve the issue, you'll need to flash a stock firmware.**

- First,  turn the phone off.
- Press and hold the following keys at the same time: Volume Down Key  + Power/Lock Key.
- Release the Power/Lock Key  only when the LG logo is displayed, then immediately press and hold the Power/Lock Key again.
- Release all keys when the Factory hard reset screen is displayed.
- Press the Power/Lock Key to continue or either of the Volume Keys  to cancel.
- Press the Power/Lock Key once more to confirm or either of the Volume Keys to cancel.

**WARNING!**

*Performing a hard reset deletes all of your user data, which includes pictures, videos, and music saved to your internal memory.*